# Least squares with equal predictors

Tags: regression, self-study, proof, weighted-regression

I am trying to figure out how to start this problem:

> We have a multivariate regression of Y on X. Show that if we have tied values for X, we can replace those by a single set and use the mean for Y with an appropriate weight. (assuming weight = I with the nth diagonal=number of tied values)

Comment: This qualifies as a routine (textbook-style) question. Please add the `self-study` tag, and since they're treated somewhat differently, please see the [tag-wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to partition (horizontally) the X-matrix and the y-vector, each into two parts, with the second part corresponding to a pair of tied x-values, and the first part being all the other observations (tied or not).

Then do the same thing with the other approach, and show that $X'X$ and $X'y$ are the same both ways.

From there arguing to the general case is straightforward (first, do the case of more than two tied observations at a single x, then you can generalize from that to ties at multiple x values immediately, since the same argument applies to each such x-value in turn)

Comment: would you just expand out the X'X into individual components then factor?

Comment: The partitioning of X leads to 4 pieces in X'X, and two in X'y. The aim is to keep those partitions, because you want to compare each piece the two different ways that are supposed to be equal. That leaves you with two parts in X'X and one in X'y that needs to be shown the same in both (the other parts are obvious).